# Delete specific row of table using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have written some code to echo my table:

```
<?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $product['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['customer_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['total_price']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['created']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $product['modified']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="delete.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile?>
```

Last td element is created for specific table row removal. However I don't know how to get that row id. This is my delete.php file:

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];

mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM orders WHERE id='".$id."'");
mysqli_close($db);
header("Location: details-modal-orders.php");
?>
```

I assume i should change something in this line:

```
<td><a href="delete.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
```

After delete.php there should be somekind of id recognizer or something. Please help. I also don't know how to create that because it is inside of a while loop. I'm afraid something is not going to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the id as a parameter via the `href` attribute

```
href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
```

Also do not forget to use prepared statements while performing this operation as it is totally unsafe to pass `$_GET` or `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` parameters directly into your query

Using prepared statments

```
$id =  (int) $_GET['id']; //cast to integer

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_prepare($db,"DELETE FROM orders WHERE id=?"); //prepare the statement returns true/fasle
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id); //bind placeholder to variable
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); //execute (returns true/false)
```

Comment: Why do you use echo? Shoul'd it be just href="delete.php?id=<?php $product['id']; ?>"> ?

Comment: `echo` would display the id. without it the variable wouldn't be displayed

Comment: @CaL17 Then why do you `<td><?php echo $product['id']; ?></td>`, shouldn't it just be `<td><?php $product['id']; ?></td>`?

Comment: otherwise you can use <?= ?>

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: pleaseure! to help

Comment: There's no need to use a prepared statement if the only data that's going in is for the GET array. Doing `(int) $_GET['id']` is enough. Just a bit of a side note here ;-)

Comment: yeah.. casting to integer is okay. I just wanted to show OP how prepared statements work. lol.. thanks @Fred-ii-

Answer (score -1):

Is it serious ?

```
<td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a></td>
```

Comment: What do you mean?